# Can't execute dockerized AWS Lambda python script

Tags: python, docker, aws-lambda

I have python script which should clone, archive and upload these archives to S3 bucket. When I'm trying to execute AWS Lambda but receiving such error:

`{ "errorType": "Runtime.InvalidEntrypoint", "errorMessage": "RequestId: b2277e15-79fe-4054-8b4a-216819021c38 Error: exec: \"lambda_function.handler\": executable file not found in $PATH" }`

It successfully executes on my local machine.
Can someone help me?

**lambda_function.py**:

```
import os
import requests
import shutil
import tarfile
import boto3

def handler(event, context):
    # GitHub organization details
    org_name = 'ORG'
    github_token = os.environ['GITHUB_TOKEN']

    # AWS S3 details
    aws_s3_bucket_name = 'SOMEBUCKETNAME'

    # GitHub API base URL
    github_api_url = 'https://api.github.com'

    # GitHub API headers with authentication token
    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'token {github_token}',
        'Accept': 'application/vnd.github.v3+json'
    }

    # Create an S3 client
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')

    # Get a list of repositories in the GitHub organization
    repos_url = f'{github_api_url}/orgs/{org_name}/repos'
    response = requests.get(repos_url, headers=headers)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        repositories = response.json()
        for repo in repositories:
            repo_name = repo['name']

            # Clone the repository locally (use AWS Lambda /tmp directory)
            os.system(f'git clone --depth 1 {repo["clone_url"]} {repo_name}')

            # Create a tar.gz archive of the repository
            with tarfile.open(f'{repo_name}.tar.gz', 'w:gz') as tar:
                tar.add(f'{repo_name}', arcname=repo_name)

            # Upload the archive to AWS S3
            s3.upload_file(f'{repo_name}.tar.gz', aws_s3_bucket_name, f'{org_name}/{repo_name}.tar.gz')

            # Clean up: remove the local clone and archive
            shutil.rmtree(f'{repo_name}')
            os.remove(f'{repo_name}.tar.gz')

    else:
        print(f'Failed to retrieve repositories. Status code: {response.status_code}')
```

**Dockerfile**:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.11
RUN yum update -y && \
    yum install -y git
COPY requirements.txt ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
COPY lambda_function.py ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD [ "lambda_function.handler" ]
```

**requirements.txt**:

```
requests
boto3
```

### UPDATE:

My workdir:

```
Dockerfile  lambda_function.py  requirements.txt
```

There is docker build command and it's output:

```
docker build --platform linux/amd64 -t gh-backup-lambda .
[+] Building 2.2s (10/10) FINISHED                                                                                                                                   docker:default
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 1.09kB                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.11                                                                                                             0.0s
 => [1/5] FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.11                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => => transferring context: 1.73kB                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => CACHED [2/5] RUN yum update -y &&     yum install -y git                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => CACHED [3/5] COPY requirements.txt /var/task                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => [4/5] COPY lambda_function.py /var/task                                                                                                                                    0.1s
 => [5/5] RUN pip install -r requirements.txt                                                                                                                                  1.8s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                                         0.1s 
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                        0.1s 
 => => writing image sha256:2de05f1b43ec4913cee4b228180e166083d4b799597d819078b62ca0da0a527f                                                                                   0.0s 
 => => naming to docker.io/library/gh-backup-lambda                                                                                                                            0.0s
```

```
aws lambda create-function --function-name githubbackup --package-type Image --code ImageUri=1111111111.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/github-backup:latest --role arn:aws:iam::1111111111:role/lambda-ex
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow  Can you show us your `docker build` command and its full output please? And your subsequent `aws lambda create-function` command? Also share output of `ls` / `dir` on Windows so we can see your directory structure. Please also verify your Lambda handler configuration in the console also matches what you have in the `Dockerfile`.

Comment: That looks fine. Are you sure the latest version of the image has been pushed?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I've updated my question as you asked. But I didn't get last one - where could I find an information about Lambda handler?

Comment: @Paolo Yes, I'm sure.

Comment: @ChoosenOne Open the Functions page of the Lambda console and choose your function. Code > Runtime settings > Function handler.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I have no Code page on my AWS Lambda function page.

Comment: Sorry, duh - you're using a container image and I meant ENTRYPOINT override. I've just created a Lambda function with the exact file you have above and the exact Dockerfile and it works perfectly fine. In that case, this isn't reproducible in its current state. Can you recreate everything from scratch, noting the commands you're using, and if the error still persists - please update the question with all of your steps?